# Why do I get no additional MessageBoxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

```
namespace övning_2._2_mitt_första_program
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult  = MessageBox.Show("Är det roligt att programera", "Övning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

            if ( DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Du suger", "ÅSNA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }

            else if (DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Klart du gör", "Duktig", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're currently using the [`Form.DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the current instance of `Form1`, instead of your `dialogResult` variable obtained from the message box. This:

```
if ( DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
```

should be:

```
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
```

(And ditto for the other branch, of course.)

Answer (score 3):

You should use your `dialogResult` variable:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogResult  = MessageBox.Show("Är det roligt att programera", "Övning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Du suger", "ÅSNA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
    else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Klart du gör", "Duktig", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough that it compiles. It takes the [`DialogResult` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) from the form instance which is `None` by default. That's why it can be a problem to use the same name for a property than the name of the  class/struct that it returns.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have made type mistake, You are storing output in variable **strong text** and comparing in variable **DialogResult**

Try this.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Är det roligt att programera", "Övning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Du suger", "ÅSNA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }

                else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Klart du gör", "Duktig", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
            }
```